# Index Markdown Files Using Lucene in Java

Tags: java, lucene, markdown

How can I index markdown files using Java & lucene so that proper weight is designated to Markdown file's Headers, Emphasis etc.

Comment: What would be the usage of weight at indexing time? I have not worked with markdown format, but I guess, you would be extracting those mentioned portions from file and storing as full text. Weight is generally useful at search time. Could you please elaborate more about what you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SabirKhan for example a bold text should have more weight than other text. Heading 1 should have more weight than heading 2. And there are some extra data which I do not want to index. Ex. [![alt text](imageurl)](linkurl). This line would mean nothing to my index.

Comment: You need to provide lucene version as well as your indexing code snippet to better understand your document structure etc. Anyway, I will write a base line answer, you provide asked details and I might edit answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the latest version of Lucene ( 6.5.1 ) , refer [Scoring — Basics](http://lucene.apache.org/core//6_5_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#package.description) section at the bottom.

In older lucene versions, you could have added boost at document level too, that is removed now and I guess that is not needed for your case either.

So, for your case, you simply need to call, `setBoost()` method for fields that you add to document.

```
Index-time boost by calling Field.setBoost() before a document is added to the index.
Query-time boost by applying a boost to a query by wrapping with BoostQuery.
```

In my codes, I have followed second approach where I boost score during searching by wrapping my Fuzzy , Phrase , Term or WildCard queries in `BoostQuery`.

Refer [BoostQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BoostQuery.html) and its constructor , `BoostQuery(Query query, float boost)`